# Is the mongo timestamp type atomic with the reads?

Tags: mongodb

I guess the title is confusing, but I could not find a better one.

I have an event stream in MongoDB with multiple producers and one consumer. To ensure that I read each event exactly once in the correct order, I use the MongoDB timestamp type as an incrementing value, populated by the server. In the SQL world I would probably use an auto-incremented integer.

My consumer just polls MongoDB and asks for all events since the last timestamp it has seen. In one of the environments we have realized that sometimes the consumer does not handle all events. It does not happen very often, like one of 50.000 events is missed, but ideally it should not happen at all.

My assumption is that MongoDB does something like this internally.

```
ParseDocument(doc);
lock 
{
   SetTimestamp(doc);
}
WriteDocument(doc);
UpdateIndex(doc);
```

So it could happen that for a very short period of time an document is not available when the consumer queries the events, because only event #1, #2 and #4 is written yet and event #3 is written a fraction of a millisecond later.

I Have seen this with a C# client and MongoDB 4.2 running in Docker, but I guess the client does not matter here.

Is this assumption correct and if yes, what can I do it?

My idea is to change my consumer to ask for all events since the last timestamp minus a few seconds and then filter out the already received events in the consumer.

But is there a more elegant solution? Perhaps some way to enforce collection level write locks or could transactions help?

Comment: What is the feature you are using that makes server generate timestamps?

Comment: It is a special type in mongodb: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#timestamps. It is contains 2 parts:

* the most significant 32 bits are a time_t value (seconds since the Unix epoch)
* the least significant 32 bits are an incrementing ordinal for operations within a given second.

When you add an empty (zero) timestamp as a second field to a document, it is a generated by the server.

Comment: Where is that documented?

Comment: Sorry, it is for all top level fields since 2.6. At the same link as above: "When inserting a document that contains top-level fields with empty timestamp values, MongoDB replaces the empty timestamp values with the current timestamp value".

Comment: I suggest using a change stream and persisting the resume token to persistent storage between invocations to maintain your position in the event stream.

Comment: I was thinking about this, but I also need to replay very old events from time to time, therefore it can only be an addition to the current solution and would it even make more complicated.

Comment: You can write a counter into the events when they are processed to give them a permanent ordering.

Comment: If I generate a counter at client side I have the same problem, but even worse. Then it will also happen that event #2 might be inserted before event #1 because of the latency to MongoDB

Comment: Change stream provides an ordered event stream, so that is not an issue.

Comment: Yes, but as I said: I cannot use change streams in all scenarios and is a very complicated solution, because when I start a consumer from beginning I need to start with pulling mode and then move over to stream mode.

Comment: What are pulling and stream modes?

Comment: If I am restarting the event consumer from beginning of time, I cannot use the event stream. Therefore I have to start with pulling. Once we are live (not sure yet how to implement that), we can continue with the change stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said "consumer" - singular, I suggest:

- Use a change stream to be notified of events. Change stream, if correctly iterated, will not skip changes nor will it return the same change twice.
- Whenever a document is returned from change stream, when it is processed by the singular consumer, add a counter to it. Since there is only one consumer it is relatively easy to implement the counter without race conditions and such.
- Also write the current resume token into each event being processed.
- If you wish, you can use the counter to uniquely identify the events.
- To iterate events again, use the counter to look up events in the past. Given that each event has both a counter and a resume token, once you get to the most recent event you can seamlessly transition from iterating based on the counter to iterating based on the resume token.

Comment: I actually implemented this solution now. I am using a normal query until (now - 5 minutes) and then I continue with the change stream. It works pretty well, also for old data sets. I do not need the continuation token with this approach and can just continue with my timestamp.